# Copy and paste data from multiple workbooks to a worksheet in another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I hope you can help. I currently have a piece of code see below. What I would like it to do is allow a user to select folder that contains workbooks. Then open each workbook select a sheet named "SearchCaseResults" from each workbook copy the data from each "SearchCaseResults" from the 2nd row down to the last used row, and paste this data into a worksheet called "Disputes" located in a different workbook in another folder.

So in PIC 1 you can see three Workbooks England, England_2 and England_3 each of these workbooks contain a worksheet "SearchCaseResults" So what I essentially need the code to do is loop through the folder open England workbook select the worksheet "SearchCaseResults" copy the data on this worksheet from row 2 to last used row then paste to the "Disputes" worksheet in the other workbook, in another folder, then select the next Workbook England_2 select the worksheet "SearchCaseResults" in this workbook copy the data on this worksheet from row 2 to last used row then **PASTE IT BELOW** the data copied from the previous worksheet(England) in the "Disputes" Worksheet and then continue with this copy and paste process until there are no more Workbooks left in the folder.

At the moment the code I have is opening up the workbooks, which is fine and selecting/activating the "SearchCaseResults" worksheet from each, but it is only coping cell A2 from the England sheets and then it is just pasting the data from the last sheet into the destination Worksheet.(I suspect the data from previous sheets is being pasted over) Can my code be amended to copy the data from each "SearhCaseResults" sheet from A2 to last used row and then Pasted into "Disputes" sheet underneath each other.

Here is my code so far as always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

CODE

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog


'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\Copy and Paste Disputes\Report Sheet\"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Copy data on "SearchCaseResults" sheet to "Disputes" Sheet in other workbook

Dim lRow As Long

Dim ws2 As Worksheet

lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\Copy and Paste Disputes\Report Sheet")

Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Disputes")

      wb.Worksheets("SearchCasesResults").Range("A2" & lRow).Copy
      With y

      ws2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
      End With



    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**I should point out that the code above is run from a separate workbook with a command button.**

See pic 2

PIC 1

[image]

PIC 2

[image]

Comment: This would be just a few clicks with the mouse if you used Power Query instead of VBA. What's your Excel version? Why are you using the xls file format that has been replaced a decade ago?

Comment: Hi Teylyn. I had never heard of Power Query and I doubt my company will allow an install. Kinda strict on what I can add to the Office package, but thank you for the awareness, as to why I am using decade old xls format, Eh I picked this piece of code up on Stack and modified to suit my needs. It may well be a decade old :-) but I just  leveraged it for today as best i could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I have corrected a few syntax errors. It's not clear if you are just copying data from column A, which I have assumed, but if not the copy line will need to be amended.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim y As Workbook

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\Copy and Paste Disputes\Report Sheet\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\Copy and Paste Disputes\Report Sheet")
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Disputes")

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Copy data on "SearchCaseResults" sheet to "Disputes" Sheet in other workbook
    With wb.Sheets("SearchCaseResults")
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:M" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    End With

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR. This is almost there. Thank you so much for the help. The last piece of the puzzle is as you expected. The copy line needs to be amended. I need it to go out to column M. Can the code be amended? Other than that it works perfectly.

Comment: Got it SLR '`.Range("A2:M" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)`

Comment: That's it, amended above now.

Comment: :-) BOO YAAA!!! lol yep having one of those days here in Dublin. SLR Thank you so much for the help. You have some wicked VBA skills. Much respect from Dublin and have a great day/ :-)

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked. Must get over to Dublin soon, great city.

Comment: Yes it is. Best Guinness in the world. Obviously :-) Thanks again

Comment: This has been very useful for me. Thank you so much!