# Copy and Paste VALUES from multiple workbooks to a worksheet in another workbook / Paste Value within Loop

Tags: vba, excel

The heavy lifting of this problem has already been solved here:

[Copy and paste data from multiple workbooks to a worksheet in another Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112239/copy-and-paste-data-from-multiple-workbooks-to-a-worksheet-in-another-workbook)

After adapting the code, I got everything to work perfectly in about 15 minutes. However, I then spent the past 3 hours scouring stackoverflow and the rest of the internet trying to figure out how to get it to paste VALUES ONLY instead of bringing over the formatting and formulas with it.

I've tried using **.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues**, but every time I try this I get an error that says "**Compile Error: Expected: end of statement**"

I've also tried using **.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)**, I get an error that says "**Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the PasteSpecial property of the Range class**"

My concern is that neither of these methods will work since there wasn't even a .Paste function to begin with.

So when I tried to just add **.Paste**, it gives me a "**Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method**"

Here's the whole code, but I'm mainly just trying to figure out how to do exactly the same with except pasting VALUES ONLY.  Thanks!

```
Sub ConsolidateAllOrdenes()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim y As Workbook

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
.Title = "Choose Target Folder Path"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xlsm*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Consolidado\Consolidado_2018-09-05a.xlsm")
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Consolidado_Orden")

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Copy data on "Orden de Compras" sheet to "consolidado_orden" Sheet in other     workbook
With wb.Sheets("Orden de Compras")
    lRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:M" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End With

wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
'Get next file name
myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "I hope that worked!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you only need the values, don't copy and paste. Just set the values - `rng1.Value = rng2.Value`.

Comment: @Comintern I had tried that earlier as well, but I just switched the line to: `ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("A5:M" & lRow).Value`,
as well as: `ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = wb.Sheets("Orden de Compras").Range("A5:M" & lRow).Value` and it just grabbed 1 cell (C3) from each workbook instead of the whole data set that it was getting before.  Not sure if i'm doing it right.

Comment: Why are you using `FldrPicker` when you already know the file you want to open?

Comment: When copying just values the range has to be the same size for both worksheets. It is not like Copy/Paste where the paste range only needs to be one cell.

Comment: I believe FldrPicker allows me to choose the folder from which i'm grabbing from so I don't have to type it in if I decide to pull all the files within a different folder.

Comment: Your Code: `ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value` selects the first empty cell in column A, not a range.

Comment: Your Code: `Workbooks.Open("C:\Consolidado\Consolidado_2018-09-05a.xlsm")` is selecting the workbook in the folder, so you don't need to use FolderPicker.

Comment: I suspect that this part: `With wb.Sheets("Orden de Compras")
    lRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:M" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End With` is what's keeping me from using the `rng1.Value = rng2.Value` way because it's defining the source file first rather than the destination file.  Then again, I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: FolderPicker is used to specify the folder where all the OTHER workbooks it's scanning through to pull from. That part is just telling it which file to make the changes to, no?

Comment: To clarify, I really don't need to change anything else from the original code above except that instead of pasting with formatting and formulas, I JUST want values. Everything works perfectly fine. I'm mainly wondering if it needs to undergo some more substantial changes and what those would be, because I'm at a loss.

Comment: I would like to help, If you are just copy/paste values from the 2 workbooks in your code you don't need `FolderPicker`, you are putting useless code in your macro. Your range needs to be written like this: `.Range("A5:M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy',

Answer (score 1):

Replace your copy/paste with this:

```
With wb.Sheets("Orden de Compras")
    Range("A2:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

Comment: Thanks! The pasting as values worked, but it missed all the copying and pasting of the specific cells I wanted based upon something in column C and from the specific tab into a continuously growing list on my master consolidated sheet.  However I did finally figured out why it wasn't letting me create another line with PasteSpecial after taking a close look at the code you provided that did allow it!!! I think it was because I hadn't defined the workbook and sheet for the first range!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm new to this, but I think I finally figured it out. I believe the range with the copy was lacking a defined workbook and sheet.

Once I specified the workbook and sheet for the copy, there was no issue with putting the paste range on another line and adding `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`.

I was also copying 2 lines from each workbook that didn't actually have anything, so I added `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets("Orden de Compras").Range("C5:C200")) <> 0 Then` and later `Else` and `End If` to skip that workbook if it didn't have anything within the range C5:C200.

I also added `Application.CutCopyMode = False` because a message box kept popping up after each file.

Replace the copy/paste with this:

```
With wb.Sheets("Orden de Compras")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets("Orden de Compras").Range("C5:C200")) <> 0 Then
    lRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wb.Sheets("Orden de Compras").Range("A5:M" & lRow).Copy
    ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else
    End If
End With
```

Thanks to everyone and especially @GMalc for the help!!!